# How to calculate the angle with given parameters (as shown)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I did actually calculate what $\theta_2$ is by finding theta3 first, but for a some angles of $\theta_1$, the answer jumps (on excel spreadsheet) to second solution (this problem has two solutions), which I dont want. I was thinking if I calculate $\theta_2$ first (somehow?) this wont be happening?

Could you please help me calculate $\theta_2$ first before  $\theta_3$ (if thats even possible), or maybe help me resolve the issue I have with Excel. Many thanks.

See the problem diagram below. All of the algebraic symbols are the given parameters apart from $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$.

[image: problem ilustration]

Here is the example of the issue I have. Excel calculations are showing me the other solutions which I dont want.

[image: problem example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, if you have two known sides and the known angle is **not** between the two known sides then you could have an ambiguous case of the sine rule.

In your diagram, call the unnamed side in the *x-z* triangle, $h$, the angle opposite $x$, $\theta_4$, and for the triangle containing $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$, call the remaining angle $\theta_5$.

I'm not sure what calculations you followed, but one way to get there is:
$$h=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$$
$$\theta_4=arctan(\frac x z)$$
$$\theta_3=90-\theta_1-\theta_4$$
Here introduce two temporary variables,
$$B=arcsin(\frac {h\cdot sin(\theta_3)} l)$$
$$X=180-B$$
At this point we can test for the ambiguous case.
If $\theta_3 + X < 180$ then we have the ambiguous case; that is, $\theta_5 = B$ or $\theta_5=X$
If it's not ambiguous, then $\theta_5=B$

There are neater ways of doing this, but here is my excel version. It assumes that where it is the ambiguous case, the *other* answer is always that one that is wanted:
[image]

Be careful though. Excel finds *atan* and *asin* between $\frac {-\pi} {2}$ and $\frac {+\pi} {2}$ which can lead to negative answers. You may need to test further for this?

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what I needed. I need exactly the same as you did to calculate the angles, but the test for ambiguous case is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\theta_3+\theta_1+\arctan (x/z)=\pi/2$$
we have $\theta_3$ in terms of the given parameters.
We also have, by the sine-rule
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}{\sin(\pi-(\theta_2+\theta_3))}=\frac{L}{\sin\theta_3}$$

So by brute-force you can also calculate $\theta_2$ in terms of $\theta_3$ and the rest of the parameters.

Comment: I did say in the question that I did manage to calculate it with theta3, but I had issues with excel giving me the solution I didnt want (since the problem has two solutions), therefore I was asking if there is a way to calculate theta2 first without calculating theta3. Im not sure if it would change anything tho.

Comment: The solution obviously does not depend on the order of calculation. About the Excel, I am afraid I have no idea what your talking about.

Comment: What can I do about it then? Im not sure what does it depend on, can I use some "if" statement to resolve it? I know that the solution jump to second one once the 3rd angle (not shown) of the second triangle is more than 90°. Ill post another picture

Answer (score 0):

Right angle at the bottom indicates that $\theta_1 + \theta_3 = \pi/2 - \arctan(x/z)$.
Sum of angles = $\pi$ indicates that 
$$\theta_2 + \theta_3 = \pi/2 - \arctan(z/x) - \arctan(x/z)$$

Comment: Actually, for the second part, replace sum of angles = 180 to sum of angles = 360, so the 90 on the second equation should be replaces by 360 - 90 = 270

Comment: So the second equation comes from the fact that the composite figure is a quadrilateral

Comment: The question I posted does say that I did solve it, but not like I wanted to, as the answer on excel is going to the solution, the one I do not want. I have added new images to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula in Excel,

$$\theta_2 = \theta_1 + \arcsin\left(\frac zL\cos\theta_1-\frac xL\sin\theta_1\right)+\arctan\frac xz -\frac\pi2$$

Make sure $\theta_1 \ge \frac\pi2 - \arctan\frac xz - \arcsin\frac L{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$ for the problem to have a solution.